# Access the facebook friend list who uses the app in ios6

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, ios6

I want to fetch the friend list who uses the same app.

I got the all facebook friend list by using SLRequest.

**But how can i fetch the facebook friend list who uses the same app?**

The same question is also be here by any one else:[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455018/facebook-installed-parameter-not-returning-data)

My code is as follow:

```
-(void)fetch
{

NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends"];

    SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                            requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                      URL:requestURL
                                               parameters:@{@"fields":@"id,name,picture,first_name,last_name,gender"}];

    request.account = self.facebookAccount;



    [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                         NSHTTPURLResponse *response,
                                         NSError *error) {

        if(!error)
        {
            list =[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

            NSLog(@"Dictionary contains data: %@", list );
            if([list objectForKey:@"error"]!=nil)
            {
                [self attemptRenewCredentials];
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
                nameLabel.text = [list objectForKey:@"username"];
            });
        }
        else{
            //handle error gracefully
            NSLog(@"error from get%@",error);
            //attempt to revalidate credentials
        }

    }];
}
```

**Problem:** If i give the request url like:

`[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=installed"];`

It shown me errorr 2500. When i use the same link with access_token in browser then i got the desired result.

**Please Help me to solve this.**

Comment: Have you tried using @{@"fields":@"id,name,picture,first_name,last_name,gender,installed"} as your "parameters" property?

Comment: @MingLi, yes it works but when i try to do the same thing in simulator then i don't able to get `installed` parameter in Response.